# How come my background image isn't being uploaded?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

I've also tried:

```css
background-image: "/media/background.jpg";
```

My background image is located in a folder called media.

ROOT-> media -> background.jpg

If I'm missing some code that would be helpful, please let me know.

Comment: Try `"./media/background.jpg";` or `"~/media/background.jpg";`. Also see here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: What's your folder structure? (Like, where is your css file compared to your background image) Your path to it most likely needs to be different than it currently is. Unless your folder 'media' is at the root of your drive, you need to check the relative path needed for your situation such as going back a folder

Comment: Yeah its in the root

Comment: I tested the same folder structure locally & this worked for me: `background-image: url("./media/background.jpg");`

Comment: If you are using Filezilla etc. enter image directory and copy the path on the program.

Answer (score -1):

```
background-image: url("../media/background.jpg");
```